# hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session throws "Session/EntityManager is closed" when set to true

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, hibernate-validator, hibernate-tools, hibernate-reactive

When we set hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session to true, it is throwing **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed** .

We are using hibernate 5.3.18.Final and spring 5.3.28 versions.

When we set hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session to false above error is not seen. However we want that property to be true in our codebase.

Could you please confirm the above error is resolved in which versions of hibernate?
or is it safe to ignore the above error?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-transactions) to true means that session will be automatically closed when the transaction completes.

If the session is already closed and then you call `EntityManager#close()` or `Session#close()` , it will throw that `IllegalStateException`. There is no harm and so you could simply  try-catch it to make the codes keep running instead of interrupted by it.

But a better idea is to use `EntityManager#isOpen()` or `Session#isOpen()` to check if the session is already closed before calling `EntityManager#close()` or `Session#close()` .

Something like :

```java
if (entityManager.isOpen()){
  entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @ken-chan.

Just wanted to know is there any compatibility issue between spring and hibernates version which we are using that causing this error?

Comment: don't think it is related. spring 5 should well support hibernate 5.3. Also if you think my answer is helpful to you , please consider to upvote it or even mark it as accepted answer. i spend so much time to research and write this answer for you for free . thanks.

Comment: I found https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel 
while searching for the issue. Just wanted to know in which version of hibernate the issue is resolved?